# How can I see output result in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

I write tic tac toe game in python and I run it in PyCharm IDE and I see result in output terminal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/INBN9.jpg

this program get input from user and show ‘O’ or ‘X’ sign in the table . I set up atom by script package terminal plus package but when RUN the program I can not see the result and system is waiting and I don’t screen for input data same PyCharm . https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK9aB.jpg

note : I run simple print command and I see the result for example 2*2 but for this program that I want to enter number or character I can not see the output !